# CodeMirror, how fold all the code

Tags: codemirror, fold

With code mirror, we can fold the code.
I would like fold all the code with brace. I found this method

How i can fold the entire code, this is my HTML script :

```
window.onload = function() {
  var te = document.getElementById("code");
  var sc = document.getElementById("script");

  var te_clike = document.getElementById("code-clike");

  window.editor_clike = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(te_clike, {
    mode: "text/x-csharp",
    lineNumbers: true,
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Q": function(cm){ cm.foldCode(cm.getCursor()); }},
    foldGutter: true,
    readOnly: true,
    gutters: ["CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"]
  });

};
```

Thanks you for your help...

Answer (score 11):

There is also a function designed to do it for you, for example:

```
editor.setOption("extraKeys", {
  "Ctrl-Y": cm => CodeMirror.commands.foldAll(cm),
  "Ctrl-I": cm => CodeMirror.commands.unfoldAll(cm),
})
```

Comment: heck yes this is the perfect answer

Comment: I found that if foldAll is called mutiple times, it would take that number of calls to unfoldAll to actually unfold the code...

Comment: Also possible to do it like this: `cm.execCommand('foldAll')`

Answer (score 8):

CodeMirror has a `foldCode` plugin which enables a `foldCode()` method. Reference can be found here: https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_foldcode

You can then loop through all the lines and call that function to fold the code at that particular line, like the solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/CodeMirror/u3IYL-5g0t4/lmK8XuTxbdQJ

```
cm.operation(function() { 
   for (var l = cm.firstLine(); l <= cm.lastLine(); ++l) 
     cm.foldCode({line: l, ch: 0}, null, "fold"); 
});
```

where `cm` is the CodeMirror instance.